# Can I use modulo to reverse output lines?

Tags: python, list, output, modulo

I've managed to get my program to print out a seating chart of a train cart similarly to what I want, but the specification of the program says that the seating chart should be printed out in a different manner (see bottom). The code looks like this:

```
while i <= rows:
j = 1
i = 1
while j <= seats:
    k = j+(4*(i-1))
    field.append("{}".format(k))  #Adds the two values to one.
    j += 1
i += 1

a = 1
b = 1
for isle in range(rows):
    for column in range(seats):
        if a == 13:
            print(" ↓ TYST AVD ↓")
        if a % 4 != 0:
            print(field[a-1].ljust(4), end='')
        else:
            print(field[a-1].ljust(4), end=''+"\n")
        a += 1
 b += 1
```

This prints out:

```
1   2   3   4   
5   6   7   8   
9   10  11  12  
 ↓ TYST AVD ↓ 
13  14  15  16  
17  18  19  20  
21  22  23  24
```

My issue is to get every other row to be reversed, i.e. I want this:

```
1   2   3   4   
8   7   6   5   
9   10  11  12  
 ↓ TYST AVD ↓
16  15  14  13  
17  18  19  20  
24  23  22  21
```

I've tried implementing modulo in a few different ways, or slice the list - which only changes the order of the numbers (e.g. it makes 24 become 42) - but I can't seem to get anything to work. Is this plausible to do with modulo, or slicing, or do I have to rethink my approach to this challenge?

Comment: Why would you use `modulo`? `l[::-1]` will return the reverse of `l`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution for your problem. Feel free to play with the rows/columns parameters to change the output.

```
from math import floor

# The parameters of seating-plan
rows = 6
columns = 4

# Create the range of seat-numbers, 
# and then "chunk" them up according to columns
seat_rows = [i for i in range(1, rows*columns+1)]
seat_rows = [seat_rows[i:i+columns] for i in range(0, len(seat_rows), columns)]

for idx, row in enumerate(seat_rows):
    # print out the indicator for the "Silent Aisles"
    # with a bias toward silent seats.
    if idx == floor(len(seat_rows) / 2):
        # Format Explanation:
        #   ^ = center text
        #   (len(row)*4)-2 = provides the width of the row to center,
        #   and centers it inside of that multiple of the width (-2).
        print("{:^{}}".format('↓ TYST AVD ↓', (len(row)*4)-2))
    # If idx is uneaven, then reverse the row.
    if idx % 2 == 1:
        row = row[::-1]
    # Creates a format-string for each entry in row
    # Format Explanation:
    #   < = aligns the text to the left
    print(("{:<4}"*len(row)).format(*row))
```

Output:

```
1   2   3   4
8   7   6   5
9   10  11  12
 ↓ TYST AVD ↓
16  15  14  13
17  18  19  20
24  23  22  21
```